# XAML: Bind to a property of a custom control from a Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, xaml-binding

in my WPF app I have a custom control with a dependency object

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeFieldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SomeField", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata((double)0, OnPropChanged));

public double SomeField
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(SomeFieldProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(SomeFieldProperty , value); }
}
```

And from my XAML I'm trying to bind to SomeField like below but it doesn't work:
**UPDATED:**

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <WrapPannel >
            <abc:MyControl SomeField="{Binding SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </WrapPannel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Tried different solutions suggested in this like questions in the StackOverflow but none of them worked. Maybe my case is a specific one as I am trying to bind from within a template?

Comment: <abc:MyControl Value="{Binding SomeField, Mode=TwoWay}" /> means you bind Value property of MyControl to a SomeField property of the datacontext... are you trying to bind some UserControl proerty to MyControl.SomeField?

Comment: By the way setting Template property of a user control may lead to really weired behavior. Use either UserControl with associated XAML or CustomControl with its style (the second is a more generic approach).

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry, I had a typo in the sample and I've updated the XAML part. So I try to bind MyControl's SomeField to a SomeValue in my ModelView.

Comment: How did you set the VM on the UserControl?

Comment: In my UserControl I have other bindings to the ViewModel, so there is on problem with the ViewModel and UserControl connection, all work fine, but this specific binding (from a Template to ViewModel doesn't take place).

Comment: Your binding looks fine. Do you have InitializeComponent() inside the constructor of your UserControl ?

Comment: Yes, I have it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not a binding problem. Actually the Template property of a UserControl is overrideb by InitializeComponent(). 
Something like this will work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <WrapPannel>
        <abc:MyControl SomeField="{Binding SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </WrapPannel>
</UserControl>
```

Actually UserControls are to be used when Templates are not needed. Otherwise use Controls, ContentControls or ItemsControls.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out, but my XAML is not as simple as I described, it contains much more data and for many reasons it should be a UserControl, so changing it would require a lot of code refactoring which I would rather prefer not to do :) That's why I asked a question here, how to make the binding work from Template. T

Comment: But what is the point of using the Template? You would like to change the style of your UserControl ?

Comment: I have a ContentPresenter in my User control <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>. And this UserControl is used in many places in the app where the Content is being set from.

Comment: So this contentPresenter template is bound to UserControl's template? if not it won't magically get the template for the content. But it won't work either as it should be a DataTemplate.

Comment: You were correct. I was not able to achieve this with my current architecture. I had to do code refactoring and the issue was gone itself. Thanks!